# Need to show result on the same page - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

I'm creating a password generator app. The app is working and stores the value on db.

The problem is whenever I refresh, the form resubmits and takes the previous value and stores.

Also, I want to show the email and password on the same page.

Whenever I refresh, I want to show an empty form with empty fields.

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
            inputemail = request.POST.get('InputEmail')
            gen = ''.join(random.choices((string.ascii_uppercase+string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits+string.punctuation), k=10))
            newpass = Item(email=inputemail,encrypt=gen)
            newpass.save()
            return render(request,'home.html',{"gen":gen})
        
    
    return render(request,'home.html',{})
```

Home.html

```
<form method = 'post' id='pass-form' >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="InputEmail" >
      <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Password</button><br><br>
  </form>
  
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Generated Password</label>
        <input type="text" id="InputPassword" name = "genpassword" value = {{gen}} >
      </div>
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to docs:

> you should always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing with POST data. This tip isn’t specific to Django; it’s good web development practice in general.

So you should make another page to show generated password, which will take submitted instance id of `Item` model created in `home` view so:

```py
def home(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        inputemail = request.POST.get('InputEmail')
        gen = ''.join(random.choices((string.ascii_uppercase+string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits+string.punctuation), k=10))
        newpass = Item(email=inputemail,encrypt=gen)
        newpass.save()
        return redirect('success', args=(newpass.pk))
       
    return render(request,'home.html',{})

def success(request, pk):
    item_obj = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    return render(request,'success.html', {'gen':item_obj.encrypt})
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('success/<int:pk>/',views.success,name='success')
]
```

success.html

```html
<body>
    <h2>The form  is successfully submitted.</h2>
    <br> 
    <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Generated Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="InputPassword" name="genpassword" value={{gen}} >
    </div>
    
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}"> Again go to password generator page.</a>
</body>
```

---

---

### Another possible solution

You can make email field `required` in Html form and then hard refresh the page after submitting the form using Javascript's `submit` event so the template:

```html
<form method='POST' id='pass-form'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="InputEmail" required>
        <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Password</button><br><br>
    </form>
    
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Generated Password</label>
        <input type="text" id="InputPassword" name = "genpassword" value ={{gen}} >
    </div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    let form =  document.getElementById('pass-form');
    addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        location.reload(true); // hard refreshed
        console.log('hard refreshed')
    });

</script>
```

> **Note:** Then also there are certain browsers like Microsoft Edge which gives pop up as ***Resubmit the form?*** in which they mention *The page you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to the page might trigger a repitition of any action you took there. Do you want to continue?*

The moment you click on continue it creates duplicacy of records, so I think as docs mentions the first approach is better.

Comment: Not sure if it's too much to ask.. It's throwing the error.
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'success' with keyword arguments '{'args': 96}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['success/(?P<pk>[^/]+)\\Z']

Comment: Also, how do I need to show the generated password on the same page? It seems your code shows generated result on the success page.

Comment: @Saassy Can you share `Item` model?

Comment: @Saassy Yes it will show generated password on success page, read the answer correctly see another possible solution I mentioned but it's better if you show it on another page as Django docs says.

Comment: It is working. Minor tweak. But, what would you suggest incase I want to show results on the same page. Some JS could help?

Comment: @Saassy You can show but you can't avoid duplicacy even with hard refresh, there must be some redirection for preventing duplicacy.